# What to call the spray of sea water?

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was at the beach, I occasionally felt the **spray of sea water**. 
Is there any word for it?

Answer (score 9):

I think it's called "[sea spray](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sea+spray)."

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for [**spindrift**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spindrift) ?

> Spindrift usually refers to spray, particularly to the spray blown
>   from cresting waves during a gale. This spray, which "drifts" in the
>   direction of the gale, is one of the characteristics of a wind speed
>   of 8 Beaufort and higher at sea. (Wikipedia, "Spindrift")

[image]

Comment: That's interesting -- my first though on reading you answer was "no, spindrift is *snow* blown off the surface".  Apparently I only knew the less-common meaning.